# Getting Unique values and adding the values in XSLT

Tags: xslt, unique

Hi I am pretty new to XSLT so need some help on simple XSL code.

My input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<Node Name="Person"  Received="1"  Good="1" Bad="0"  Condition="byPerson:1111">
</Node>
<Node Name="Person"  Received="1"  Good="1" Bad="0"  Condition="byPerson:1111">
</Node>
<Node Name="Person"  Received="1"  Good="1" Bad="0"  Condition="byPerson:2222">
</Node>
<Node Name="Person"  Received="1"  Good="1" Bad="0"  Condition="byPerson:2222">
</Node>
<Node Name="Person"  Received="1"  Good="1" Bad="0"  Condition="byPerson:3333">
</Node>
```

And i am expecting the result as sum of all Received , good and Bad but that need to added only once per unique condition.

Something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<Received>3</Received >
<Good>3</Good>
<Bad>0</Bad>
```

i was trying below code but no success so far just getting sum of everything, would like to get sum on only each 'Condition' only once.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">


<xsl:template match="/">


<xsl:value-of select= "sum(Node@Received)"/>
<xsl:value-of select= "sum(Node/@Good)"/>
<xsl:value-of select= "sum(Node/@Bad)"/>  


</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your input is not well-formed XML. So, you would want the sum of those attributes for each of the three unique Conditions? Repeat those three elements for the 3 unique conditions?

Answer (score 1):

The following stylesheet uses an [`xsl:key`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key) to group the `<node>` elements by the value of the `@Condition`. Using the [Meunchien method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) with [`key()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-key) and [`generate-id()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-generate-id), to select the first `node` element for each unique `@Condition` and then generate the [`sum()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-sum) of the attributes of the selected `node` elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="nodesByCondition" match="Node" use="@Condition"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <results>

            <xsl:variable name="distinctNodes" 
                select="*/Node[generate-id() = 
                generate-id(key('nodesByCondition', @Condition)[1])]"/>

            <Received>
                <xsl:value-of select= "sum($distinctNodes/@Received)"/>
            </Received>
            <Good><xsl:value-of select= "sum($distinctNodes/@Good)"/></Good>
            <Bad><xsl:value-of select= "sum($distinctNodes/@Bad)"/></Bad>                
        </results>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Hansen for your Quick Response.. actually i was expecting more of as following, if 1111 comes in it should count the Received as just one, so for 1 condtional value it should be just one and increment for next unique condition value.

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
     <Received>3</Received >
     <Good>3</Good>
     <Bad>0</Bad>

Comment: Okay, so the assumption is that the nodes matching a given `@Condition` will be uniform? There won't be some matching 1111 that have different values for `@received, `@good`, or `@bad`?

Comment: Yes if condition is 1111 the subsequent values will be same, all i need is count the first occurances of a  distinct condition, the above answer gives me all Zeros, do i need to add an for each condition, so that it can sum up ? Thanks again

Comment: Hi Hansen, Any update on this would be greatly helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: What does you input XML look like? What you posted is not well-formed and cannot be parsed. I added a document element to wrap that content, and the stylesheet expects that the `Node` elements are nested under that document element. You may need to adjust the XPath in the `distinctNodes` select statement to match your XML structure.

Comment: Thanks Hansen, let me try with the input xml and see what it generates.

Answer (score 0):

in XSLT 2.0 you can use **distinct-values()**